# Azure Resource Manger - Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts vs microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

What is the difference between `microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts` and `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts`?

Running the following commands

`> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager`

`> Get-AzureLocation`

Results in:

**Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts**

- East US
- East US 2
- West US
- West Europe
- East Asia
- Southeast Asia
- Japan East
- Japan West
- North Central US
- South Central US
- Central US
- North Europe

**microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts**

- East Asia
- Southeast Asia
- East US
- East US 2
- West US
- North Central US
- South Central US
- Central US
- North Europe
- West Europe
- Japan East
- Japan West
- Brazil South
- Australia East
- Australia Southeast

You can see that `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts` are not avaliable in any of the Australian data centers.

Should I use `microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts` in my azure resource manager template so I can target an australian region, or will this storage type ultimately be deprecated so I'm better of going with `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts` in another location?

Comment: What region are you using?  Brazil South is the only region that has ClassicStorage but not Storage.

Comment: I have added extra information

Comment: Interesting, I'm in the US and the Australia regions don't show up under `microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts` when I do `Get-AzureLocation`.  Regardless, I think it's safe to say that the `classic*` providers will eventually go away.  Also, you should be aware that ARM features like tags and RBAC are not available with classic resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, the new Azure Resource Manager (ARM) stack (Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts) does not support Australia East and Southeast (or Brazil South). So you cannot currently create a storage account in these regions via the ARM stack.

The portal is based on the older Azure Service Management (ASM) stack (microsoft.classicstorage/storageAccounts), and these locations are supported via this stack. That's why it's possible to create them via the portal. The same is true with PowerShell, if you are using the Service Management PowerShell cmdlets.

We recommend that users move to the ARM stack if possible, as that will eventually supercede the ASM stack.